# Do you need to check Google Play Services connection in every activity?

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I have followed this tutorial and gotten working code:http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/google-play-services-setup.html . Google design guidelines seem to say that it is paramount that the services are verified in the application. However, by only running GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this); in my MainActivity, aren't I opening up a vulnerablity in other activities? I feel like it may. If I add in add that code though, it will make things much messier. What is the proper way?

Comment: You could create an asynctask class that does the check in a background thread for you and call that asynctask from any other activity with a line or 2 of code. You don't need to do the check, but you are correct there are a few instances where it could cause breaks in your app.

Comment: Thanks for responding. It seems like it's not worth the trouble of  task managing for such an edge case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would only bother checking in MainActivity.

That method is about checking whether PlayServices is available. If you have checked it once that is sufficient. The worse case is that they uninstall PlayServices while still in your app and your next Play Services call fails. Highliy unlikely and probably low risk (depending on your's app stability requirements).